# documentation for jQuery AjaxUpload()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

Can anyone point me in the direction of a documentation page for jQuery's AjaxUpload() function? I'm trying to build a multiple file upload, and i need to pass parameters along with the files, but i am unsure on how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://github.com/valums/file-uploader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation is here [github.com/valums/file-uploader](http://github.com/valums/file-uploader). Multi file upload should work without explicitly setting it as a parameter. Look at [this](http://valums.com/files/2010/file-uploader/demo.htm) demo.

Comment: New one is not available freely. You need to purchase license.

Comment: @JenniferMichelle That's `Fine Uploader`, it doesn't seem to be the same thing.

Comment: Fine Uploader _is_ the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Even if actually is not part of jQuery core, but a plugin