# AjaxUpload Display file uploading progress

Tags: jquery

```
<script>
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload1, {
    action: 'http://example.com/addfile.php',
    name: 'uploadfile',
    fid: 'uploadfile1',
    dataType:'json',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){

    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
        alert("File Uploaded");
    }
});
</script>
```

I want to display progress bar on file upload.

Can anyone suggest me for this how can i display progress bar for this AjaxUpload ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=settimout&oq=settimout&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2419j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=progress+bar+in+jquery+with+percentage

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/q/9899614/1741542 and https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader

Answer (score 0):

```
function sample(){
$('.progressbar').show();
new AjaxUpload(btnUpload1, {
    action: 'http://example.com/addfile.php',
    name: 'uploadfile',
    fid: 'uploadfile1',
    dataType:'json',
    onSubmit: function(file, ext){

    },
    onComplete: function(file, response){
        alert("File Uploaded");
        $('.progressbar').hide();
    }
});
}
```

Comment: Please google it you will get so many progress bar options http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Actually prash i just want to add progress bar on this code. b'coz i don't want to add other progress bar. b'coz i already added this AjaxUpload at many place.